# Epson printer TM-T20III , error The information is not desctribed in XML - Linux

Tags: printing, javapos

I'm working on implementing a Epson TM-T20III printer to our system, i'm getting this error when opening the printer

```
jpos.JposException: The information is not described in XML.
        at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.initializeServiceSetting(CommonPrinterService.java:1468) ~[epsonjpos.jar:?]
        at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.T88IIService.initializeServiceSetting(T88IIService.java:825) ~[epsonjpos.jar:?]
        at jp.co.epson.upos.T20II.pntr.T20IIService.initializeServiceSetting(T20IIService.java:81) ~[epsonjpos.jar:?]
        at jp.co.epson.upos.core.v1_14_0001.pntr.CommonPrinterService.open(CommonPrinterService.java:1292) ~[epsonjpos.jar:?]
        at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(BaseJposControl.java:538) ~[javapos-controls-1.14.2.jar:1.14.4]
        at com.wps.pms.epson.jpos.AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.openThePrinter(AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.java:215) ~[epsonprinterservice-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wps.pms.epson.jpos.AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.init(AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.java:252) ~[epsonprinterservice-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wps.pms.epson.jpos.AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.startPrinterCommunicationAndReturnServiceState(AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.java:268) ~[epsonprinterservice-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wps.pms.epson.jpos.AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.onStartingAndReturnState(AbstractEpsonPrinterServiceImpl.java:281) ~[epsonprinterservice-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wps.pms.service.AbstractService.startService(AbstractService.java:126) ~[service-lib-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wps.pms.localservicesmanager.service.LocalServicesManagerImpl$AsyncStartServiceTask.runTask(LocalServicesManagerImpl.java:1039) ~[localservicesmanager-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.wps.pms.threading.timer.AbstractTimerTask.run(AbstractTimerTask.java:24) ~[threading-2.33.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:V2.33.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_362]
```

here is the jpos.xml

```
 <JposEntries>
      <JposEntry logicalName="TM-T20III">
        <creation factoryClass="jp.co.epson.uposcommon.creator.EpsonJposServiceInstanceFactory" serviceClass="jp.co.epson.upos.T20II.pntr.T20IIIService"/>
        <vendor name="SEIKO EPSON" url="http://www.epson.com"/>
        <jpos category="POSPrinter" version="1.14"/>
        <product description="EPSON TM-T20III Printer Device Service" name="EPSON Services for JavaPOS(TM) Standard" url="http://www.epson.com"/>
        <prop name="PhysicalDevice" type="String" value="TM-T20III"/>
        <prop name="PortName" type="String" value="TM-T20III"/>
        <prop name="PortType" type="String" value="2"/>
        <prop name="PortNameType" type="String" value="0"/>
        <prop name="epson.tracing" type="String" value="false"/>
        <prop name="UsePCS" type="String" tvalue="false"/>
      </JposEntry>
    </JposEntries>`
```

This linux environment , what is missing here. please support. thank you

different jpos.xml files